# Unicode text confounding Mysql queries

Tags: mysql, csv, unicode

I have a PHP script that extracts attachments (Unicode text csv files) from gmail and uploads them to a mysql database.  All of that works fine.  But once in the database I cannot run the simplest of queries against the data.

If I first bring the file into Excel then export as a CSV file then all works fine, I can query and get the expected results.

I have done enough reading to understand (I think) that the issue is somehow related to the fact that Unicode text is either UTF8 or UTF16, but when I convert the table to either of those, the data comes in fine but I still cannot run a successful query.

Update:
I have an individual named White in the lastrep column of the data.  The only way I can pull the associated records is by using wild cards between characters, as in:

```
SELECT * FROM `dailyactual` WHERE `lastrep` like "%W%h%i%t%e%"
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Use the UTF8MB4 collation. Instructions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-upgrading.html

Answer (score 0):

In utf8 or utf8mb4 *character set*, 'White' would be 'White' (hex `57 68 69 74 65`).  In utf16, there would be (effectively) a zero byte between each character; hex: `0057 0068 0069 0074 0065`.

Can you get a hex dump of part of the file?

If you can specify the output of excel, do so.  Else specify the input for mysql to be utf16 or whatever the encoding says.  Since there are many ways of bringing a csv file into mysql, I can't be more specific.